# highlight.js не работает при маршрутизации AngularJS (ui.router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

По инструкции highlightjs.org подключаю плагин подсветки кода

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.1.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://yastatic.net/highlightjs/8.2/highlight.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Если не использовать маршрутизацию блок с кодом подсвечивается нормально, в противном случае(если контент подгружается при роутинге ui.router) не подсвечивается.
Кто сталкивался. как решить эту проблему?
Пробовал при смене state прописывать

```
 setTimeout(function() {
                        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
                    });
```

не помогло, хотя когда-то аналогичное решение, а именно

```
 setTimeout(function() {
                        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
                    });
```

помогло для отображения формул mathjax

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить инициализацию внутри конкретного контроллера. При этом вместо setTimeout лучше использовать обертку на него от angular - $timeout.
Что то вроде этого:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('MainCtrl', function($timeout) {
 $timeout(function() {
   hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
 });
});
```

Comment: нет функции `$setTimeout`, либо `setTimeout`, либо `$timeout`

Comment: @Grundy да, запамятовал. Моё упущение. Писал не до конца проснувшись.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла ручная инициализация

```
$('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
                            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                        });
```

Comment: С точки зрения angular это плохое решение

Comment: Можно вместо этого написать директиву обертку.

Comment: а еще можно воспользоваться уже написанной: https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

Comment: @Grundy да как правило лучше сразу поискать существующие решения прежде чем писать свой велосипед.